# How to configure a proxy for conda/anaconda both via http and https?

Tags: python, tensorflow, proxy, installation, anaconda

I am currently using Python `(Version: 3.5.2 |Anaconda 4.2.0 (64-bit)|)`. While i am trying to install tensorflow , it is throwing an error. 
Reason is i am behind a proxy , so i need to configure a proxy for conda. I saw some old posts regarding this, but could not understand. Could anyone please help me ??

Answer (score 0):

Go to your directory where Anaconda3 is being installed
create a new file of type `.condarc`

In that file enter the following configuration for your proxies

```
proxy_servers:
    http: http://your_proxy:port_number
    https: https://your_proxy:port_number
```

[image: The file should look like this]

Comment: Thank for the reply. But it did not work for me.. Could you please suggest any other solution.

Comment: where have you saved this file?

Comment: In Anaconda folder only,where Menu,Pkgs,Scripts all these folders are there.

Comment: @ssp could you show me your .conarc file, how it looks?